# Stopping Spark Streaming: exception in the cleaner thread but it will continue to run

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm working on a Spark-Streaming application, I'm just trying to get a simple example of a Kafka Direct Stream working:

```
package com.username

import _root_.kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

object MyApp extends App {
  val topic = args(0) // 1 topic
  val brokers = args(1) //localhost:9092
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[2]").getOrCreate()
  val sc = spark.sparkContext
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
  val topicSet = topic.split(",").toSet
  val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> brokers)
  val directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicSet)

  // Just print out the data within the topic
  val parsers = directKafkaStream.map(v => v)
  parsers.print()

  ssc.start()
  val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000) // 5 second loop

  while(System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime){
    //write something to the topic
    Thread.sleep(1000) // 1 second pause between iterations
  }

  ssc.stop()
}
```

This mostly works, whatever I write into the kafka topic, it gets included into the streaming batch and gets printed out. My only concern is what happens at `ssc.stop()`:

```
dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss WARN FileSystem: exception in the cleaner thread but it will continue to run
java.lang.InterruptException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    at java.lang.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsDataReferenceCleaner.run(FileSystem.java:2989)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This exception doesn't cause my app to fail nor exit though. I know I could wrap `ssc.stop()` into a try/catch block to suppress it, but looking into the API docs has me believe that this is not its intended behavior. I've been looking around online for a solution but nothing involving Spark has mentioned this exception, is there anyway for me to properly fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem with starting the process directly with sbt run. But if I packaged the project and start with `YOUR_SPARK_PATH/bin/spark-submit --class [classname] --master local[4] [package_path]`, it works correctly. Hope this would help.

Comment: I'm running this on Intellij IDEA, not the command line. My SBT tasks consist of `clean compile "runMain <com.username.AppClass> <arguments>"`, I set the master in my code. Am I missing the package path? What would like look like?

Comment: Do you have a Spark cluster running?

Comment: Yes, I ran `./sbin/start-master.sh` and `bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://<user>:7077`